# Whenever I try to run Chrome using selenium using Python I get this error. has anyone experienced this before?

Tags: python, selenium

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r"C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("http:/https://stackoverflow.com/")
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Intro.py", line 3, in 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r"C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\chromedriver.exe")
File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 76, in **init**
RemoteWebDriver.**init**(
File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in **init**
self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: failed to write prefs file

Answer (score 0):

This can cause if your C drive has not enough space. So use any tools like Disk Cleaner or CCleaner to free up some space.

Comment: Still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version of the working code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Windows\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
```

Try adding chromedriver to C:\Windows.
Check both chrome and chromedriver having the same version.